# firestore the getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I try to count all docs from one user in firestore.
My code:

```
  Widget booksWidget(String userData) {                            
    return
    StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("bookList")
            .doc(userData)
            .collection(userData)
            .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot)  {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var userDocument = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot?;
            String books = userDocument?.length.toString();
            return Text(books);
          }else{
            return Text("none");
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

the error:

```
The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'.
```

thanks for help, streambuilder after migration to null-safety is quite different :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting the snapshots of a query, so the `snapshot.data` that you get is going to be of type `QuerySnapshot` (and not a `DocumentSnapshot?` as you assume now).

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  var querySnapshot = snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot;
  String books = querySnapshot.docs.length.toString();
  ...
```

In cases like this I find it easiest to work from the reference documentation, such as the one for [`Query.snapshots()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) here.

Comment: thank you very much, works for me. I just had to add a .docs in front of .length. maybe you can update your answer for others

Comment: Good catch @Bernhard, I updated the code in my answer . For such typos you can also edit the answer yourself, as it's clearly not conflicting with what I intended. 